# Riding a wet clutch on corners

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, shifting

This question only applies to wet clutches.

Say you're going at 30mph in 3rd gear and the road ahead has an upcoming bend such that a downshift is warranted - the bike would begin to shudder if you took it on in current gear at a safe speed.

But for whatever reason suppose you're lazy. You notice that if you remain in 3rd with no throttle and just pull the clutch in slightly as your speed drops off, you appear to be able to get around the bend smoothly, and then just release the clutch again as you exit the bend while giving a little throttle. It certainly feel smooth, and quiet (no downshift + rev-match required), but does it damage your clutch an unacceptable amount?

Is it just bad for control of the vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Be in the right gear all the time, and fully release the clutch. If you have to slip the clutch while moving, you're in too high a gear. The clutch should be remain in the friction zone only when you're starting from a stop; it should thereafter pass througt the friction zone only when you're shifting.

The problem is two-fold:

First, the clutch is slipping. That means more wear than is necessary. Whether it's *too much* wear is a matter of opinion, and not suitable for this question-and-answer site. I take a hard line here: don't slip the clutch unless you're starting out from a stop. Why would you want to generate unnecessary wear?

Second, when you're holding the clutch in the friction zone some of your attention is diverted away from the motorcycle's attitude and position on the road into attention to the clutch lever's position and effect. Anything that takes attention away from what you're doing on the roadway is undesirable. Motorcycling carries significant physical risk, and is not a place for divided attention. Staying upright and alive requires persistent and applied consciousness.

An exception is staying upright at very slow speeds (i.e., below the speed that would be generated if the motor were idling in the lowest gear), which requires a slipping clutch. This is not, however, an appropriate tactic for riding at any speed higher than that of an idling engine.

I'll close with this: you assume in your question that this issue only applies to wet (i.e., oil bath) clutches. It doesn't. All clutches wear, both dry and wet. The more they're slipped, the more they wear.

Source: 48 years of motorcycle street riding: no accidents, no damage to bikes, and no injuries to myself or others. Professional motorcycling instructor for ten years in the California Motorcyclist Safety Program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to add, I'm not sure if this is how they teach in the US but in the UK when manoeuvring at low speed, e.g. the U turn or slow crawl parts of the motorcycle exam, the taught technique is actually to feather the clutch in 1st gear - with throttle - and use rear brake to control speed.

Comment: @sphere Thanks, you are quite correct; staying upright at _very_ slow speeds (i.e., below the speed that would be generated if the motor were idling in the lowest gear) requires a slipping clutch. This is not, however, an appropriate tactic for riding at any higher speed. I'll amend the answer.